# populating mysql database

Tags: mysql, large-files

I have a file with over a million lines of data, each line is a record.

I can go through the file, read the line and do a insert, but this can take up to 2 hours. Is there a faster way like uploading a sql file?

Comment: I don't think you can *quickly* insert over a million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find and replace to build an insert statement around it.